# Convert FLV video with alpha channel to PNGs with transparency

Tags: ffmpeg, png, imagemagick, flv, alpha-transparency

I have some FLV videos with alpha channels, and I want to convert each of them to PNG images using ffmpeg but keep the transparency.

So far, I've tried this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -an -y %d.png
```

But this outputs the PNG files with black background.

Is there any way to do this?

*Alternate acceptable solution*: If I can output the images and give the alpha channel a certain color of my choice. I can then remove it later via imagemagick and convert that color to transparency.

Comment: Eg: `convert -transparent white example.png example2.png`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know its quite late for an answer but I was searching for a similar solution and found this : ffmpeg -i video.flv -r 25 -vcodec png -pix_fmt rgb32 %d.png